# I want to convert in datetime format in datastage

Tags: datastage

I want to get my output file with specific date time format
yyyymmddhhmmss all withoiut separation, am using the following code trim(oconv(date(),"D YMD[4,2,2]")," ","A"):"(":Convert(":","_",Oconv(time(),'TI')):") in my master    but am obataining >>>  yyyy mm dd (hh_mm_ss_pm)
Your help will be really appreciated 
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a certain separation symbol and replace it afterwards as date and time cannot be directly generated without any separation symbol.

So this should solve your problem:

`Ereplace(oconv(date(),"D:YMD[4,2,2]") : ":" : Oconv(time(),'MTS'), ":", "")`

Comment: Thank you alot Michael it works really apreaciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You must use Activity Variable on Value Expression of Job Activity parameter.
For example:

```
EREPLACE(OCONV(DATE(),'D:YMD[4,2,2]') : '_':OCONV(TIME(),'MTS'), ':', '_')
```